# How to have two condition a query for Spotify API in python

Tags: python, spotify

I want to have at least two condition in the query. I am trying to put a random word and a giving year to search.

```
get_valid = False # Initialize 

while get_valid == False:
    random_word = "random"
    year = "2010"
    # Search for tracks
    search_query = f"{random_word}&year:{year}"
    results = sp.search(q=search_query, type='track', limit=10)
    # Print the track names and artists
    for track in results['tracks']['items']:
        track_name = track['name']
        artists = [artist['name'] for artist in track['artists']]
        release_date = track['album']['release_date']
        release_date_split = release_date.split("-")
        if len(release_date_split) == 3:
            release_year = release_date_split[0]
            release_month = release_date_split[1]
            print(f"Track: {track_name}, Artists: {', '.join(artists)}, Release Date: {release_date}", {release_year})
            song_title = track_name
            get_valid = True
```

have try different format but does not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, you just need to add spaces between your conditions and the logical & operator in the query i.e.

```py
search_query = f"{random_word} & year:{year}"
```